# NestedScrollView не получается добавить второй блок

Tags: android, android-xml, cardview, collapsing-toolbar-layout, nested-scrollview

Пытаюсь сделать что,то похожее на это, на сколько понял делается это всё через `androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView`, `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` и `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Один CardView сделал, хочу еще один добавить, но не получается. Пытался через `android:layout_marginTop="8dp"` ,      `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/название"` и `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"`, но без успешно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Settings.SettingsActivity">


<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <ImageView
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:src="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                android:title="@string/recent_news"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
>
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    >

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="12dp">
                <ImageView
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_clock"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </ImageView>
                <TextView
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:padding="12dp"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="@string/date"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="9"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ed"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>
```